# Open-Source Лицензия

Tags: лицензирование, opensource

есть ли Open-Source лицензия похожая на GPL для ПО но это лицензия должна предусматривать.

1. Нельзя изменять лицензию ПО на другую (АБСОЛЮТНО!!!) при модификации, изменении, распространении и т.д
2. ПО основанное на данном продукте обязано лицензироваться по той же лицензии.

Comment: Ну так GPL именно для этого и создавался, чем он вас не устроил?

Answer (score 2):

> Нельзя изменять лицензию ПО на другую (АБСОЛЮТНО!!!) при модификации, изменении, распространении и т.д

любая лицензия, где явно не оговорено обратное (случай редкий, в качестве иллюстрации, вероятно, подойдёт какая-нибудь экзотика типа [wtfpl](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WTFPL)), соответствует данному требованию в части «распространение». ибо запрет модифицировать (не распространяя), насколько мне известно, юридически ничтожен в любой юрисдикции мира.

> ПО основанное на данном продукте обязано лицензироваться по той же лицензии.

любая лицензия, где явно не оговорено обратное, соответствует данному требованию.

---

но вообще такое требование относится не столько к лицензии как таковой, сколько к уведомлению о её использовании, включённому в файлы с исходниками.

например, [рекомендаванное fsf](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-howto.html) уведомлнение, включающее абзац, в котором явно оговорена возможность (на усмотрение программиста) распространять текст программы и/или модификации под «версией 3 **или** любой последующей»:

```
Foobar is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
(at your option) any later version.
```